# Org-mode 8.3: Beamer blocks without title no longer work?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

I recently upgraded my org-mode from 8.2 to 8.3. So far all works well, but I ran into the following problem: when creating a LaTeX Beamer presentation in org-mode I used to be able to do the following to get a block without a title:

```
**                                  :B_block:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
   Text in block without title
```

With Org 8.3 I get the text `:B_block:` as title of the block instead of not title at all.

Here is a MWE:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+TITLE: A title
#+DATE: 2015-09-17
#+AUTHOR: The Presenter

#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid

# The following line gives access to the C-c C-b key for headings
#+startup: beamer


* Introduction
** A block                              :B_block:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
   Some text in the block.
**                                  :B_block:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
   Text in block without title
```

With Org 8.2 this gives the following slide:
[image: What I used to get and what I like to have]

And Org 8.3 gives:
[image: What I currently get]

I didn't find anything related in the Changelog. Did I miss something or have I found a bug? Or have I made some practical use of a bug that has now been 'fixed' ;-)?

Comment: It is a "feature". See this thread in the org-mode mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00768.html

Comment: @rvf0068 actually, in the thread you point, a workaround is suggested using `\phantom{dummy}` ; but I can't manage to find how to use it exactly :-/

Answer (score 3):

I think it works ok if you remove the `:B_block:` from your headlines.

```
* Introduction
** A block                            
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_env: block
   :END:
   Some text in the block.
** 
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: block
:END:
   Text in block without title
```

leads to:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, removing the `:B_block:` works, in principle. However, in my `.emacs` I have added a `before-save-hook` that cleans whitespace. And for your suggestion to work, I need at least one space after the `**` header. So, while your suggestion is OK in general, I would like to find a way that works with my setup.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that @Lgen gave works as far as the export is concerned, but it breaks visibility cycling (the headline level is lifted). As the [thread](http://%20lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00768.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml) on the org-mode mailing list suggests, empty headlines are considered evil. So I'd propose to insert something that has no effects export-wise, for example `@@latex:@@`. With this, you can also keep the tag, which I find useful as a visual marker of blocks in beamer.

```
** @@latex:@@                     :B_block:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: block
:END:
   Text in block without title
```